# Rocks Cluster Distribution - How do you install an .rpm manually in the post install script

Tags: rpm, yum, rocks

One of my rpms can yum install properly when done manually, but for some reason it is breaking the install process when I reboot a node after making a new distribution including that particular package.

I am wondering if I can circumvent the issue by just running 'yum install package.rpm' in the post-install section of extend-compute or something?

Or, it would be equally helpful if someone can give me a tip as to why a package would break the install in the first place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible, and I definitely wouldn't recommend it.

I would guess the RPM database would be locked so it would just hang.

Simply make the other RPM required.